# gnu parallel: quoted arguments and spaces in file names. How to solve?

Tags: ffmpeg, gnu-parallel

This is driving me crazy.

I have a bunch of mp3 that I want to transcode using `ffmpeg`.

I'm trying to use this one-liner (the script is bigger, this is the problematic section):

```
find . -type f \( -iname \*.mp3 \) | parallel ffmpeg -i "{}" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k "$output_folder_with_spaces/{.}-128k.mp3" \;
```

(The `iname` section is there because in the future more extensions will maybe be used)

But even using the quotes in `{}`, I always get `No such file or directory`, cause the mp3 is named `01 - My song`. And I don't know if `"$output_folder_with_spaces"` is going to work either.

I've googled a lot, but can't find this example: using `{}` from `find` that `{}` has spaces. I've only found when using a variable or hardcoded paths in quotes.

Anyone knows how I can solve this space problem, in this scenario?

Comment: Shouldn't you be `-exec`-ing `ffmpeg` on the results of the `find` command, rather than piping them to it?

Comment: @don_crissti the filename itself without extension.

Comment: @steeldriver There was a parallel in there as well. The problem is not with the piping tough, I have a similar setup but for converting videos and it works. But if you have a -exec solution that solves the space issue, no problem.

Comment: Please always include the exact error message when asking a question.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the wrong replacement string with `parallel`; you'll also need `-q` to pass quoted arguments and I'm not sure what the trailing `\;` does...
Example:

```
dirname_with_spaces="/home/don/my dir with spaces/"
```

(note the trailing `/` in the path assigned to `dirname_with_spaces`) and some `mp3` file names with spaces under a `test` directory, right under `cwd`:

```
./test/Commercial DEMO - 09.mp3
./test/Commercial DEMO - 11.mp3
./test/Handel Royal Fireworks - 07.mp3
./test/Jazz Rag Ensemble - 10.mp3
./test/Mouret - Rondeau.mp3
```

using

```
find . -type f -iname \*.mp3 | parallel -q ffmpeg -i {} -acodec \
libmp3lame -ab 128k "$dirname_with_spaces"{/.}-128k.mp3
```

produces the following files:

```
/home/don/my dir with spaces/Commercial DEMO - 11-128k.mp3
/home/don/my dir with spaces/Commercial DEMO - 09-128k.mp3
/home/don/my dir with spaces/Handel Royal Fireworks - 07-128k.mp3
/home/don/my dir with spaces/Jazz Rag Ensemble - 10-128k.mp3
/home/don/my dir with spaces/Mouret - Rondeau-128k.mp3
```

Note the command line `q`uoting (`parallel -q`) and the usage of:

```
{}
    Input line.
```

which means the path from `find` output e.g. `./test/Mouret - Rondeau.mp3`
and

```
{/.}
    Basename of input line without extension.
```

which expands to `Mouret - Rondeau` and then  `"$dirname_with_spaces"{/.}` expands to `/home/don/my dir with spaces/Mouret - Rondeau`

The latter is quite different from the `{.}` used in your command

```
{.}
    Input line without extension.
```

which would expand to `./test/Mouret - Rondeau` and then  `"$dirname_with_spaces"{.}` would expand to `/home/don/my dir with spaces/./test/Mouret - Rondeau`. Obviously, this will error out as there is no `/./test/` under `/home/don/my dir with spaces`.

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood `find`'s syntax. The `{}` syntax is used in conjunction with `-exec`. Also, those parentheses you have aren't needed; you only need them if you want to override the default order of operations (e.g., not evaluate from left-to-right). Overall, with exec, it'd look something like this (split to avoid horizontal scroll):

```shell
find . -type f -iname \*.mp3 -exec \
    ffmpeg -i "{}" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k \
    "$output_folder_with_spaces/{}-128k.mp3" \;
```

Note that'll give you files named like `foo.mp3-128.mp3` … I hope that's what you wanted; I have no idea what `{.}` was supposed to mean—it's not valid syntax, at least with GNU find.

I'd suggest using `lame` directly though, instead of through FFmpeg (and if `-ab` uses ABR mode instead of VBR mode, I'd suggest against that without good reason). Actually, I'd suggest against re-encoding MP3s in general; better quality at the same bit rate would be obtained by encoding from a lossless source.

Comment: I'm reencoding to use in a low end device. Thanks for your warning though.

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS Ok. "Hardware limitations" count as a good reason. You may also need to find ffmpeg's equivalent of LAME's `-B`.

Comment: Your exec works. But I still can't understand why the pipe solution fails only with spaces, I have the same script but for converting videos (without spaces) and it works. Do you have an explanation? Or was I wrong from the beginning and working was just a matter of luck?

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS I'll add in a *guess* for what might work... I don't have GNU Parallel installed to test with (and it conflicts with moreutils).

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS added.

Comment: The parallel doesn't work, now I get "Unable to find a suitable output format for $output_folder_with_spaces".

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS sounds like parallel is doing something weird... what if you do an `export output_folder_with_spaces` and then use `"\$output_folder_with_spaces/{.}-128k.mp3"` (note the backslash before the `$`) ?

Comment: Now I get "No such file or directory" again. :) I think I will just give up parallel.

Comment: @SomebodystillusesyouMS-DOS Ok. I'm going to edit out my guess since its apparently wrong.